# Change a word based upon the file content

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have a file which contains timestamp and date in the second column. If the line contains one of the word then it need to be replace like below.

```
File:
a smallint
b timestamp
c date
d varchar

O/P:
a smallint
dateformat(b,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS.sss')
dateformat(c.'YYYY-MM-DD')
d varchar
```

If I execute this below command as a single awk then I am getting output but if I use else condition then I am getting error.

```
awk '{if ($2=="timestamp") {$3="dataformat("; }; print $3 $1 ",'\''YYYY-MM-DD HH'\:'NN'\:'SS'\.'sss)" else ($2=="date") {$3="dataformat("; }; print $3 $1 ",'\''YYYY-MM-DD)" }' test.out
```

Error:

```
awk: {if ($2=="timestamp") {$3="dataformat("; }; print $3 $1 ",'YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS.sss)" else ($2=="date") {$3="dataformat("; }; print $3 $1 ",'YYYY-MM-DD)" }
awk: ^ syntax error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write:

```
awk -v q="'" '
    $2 == "timestamp" { $0 = sprintf("dateformat(%s, "q"YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS.sss"q")", $1) }
    $2 == "date"      { $0 = sprintf("dateformat(%s, "q"YYYY-MM-DD"q")", $1) }
                      { print }
' file
```

Comment: Great call on the single quotes and using `q` for that!

Comment: @glenn jackman and it worked.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Let me wrap the lines in your command first:

```
awk '
    {
        if ($2=="timestamp") {
            $3="dataformat("; 
        };
        print $3 $1 ",'\''YYYY-MM-DD HH'\:'NN'\:'SS'\.'sss)"
        else ($2=="date") {
            $3="dataformat("; 
        };
        print $3 $1 ",'\''YYYY-MM-DD)"
    }
' test.out
```

So, two problems there, one is that the `else` clause does not align with the `if` clause (there's a `print` command outside it) and the second is that the `else` clause doesn't take a condition, you want to use `else if` instead.

So maybe this is what was intended instead?

```
awk '
    {
        if ($2=="timestamp") {
            $3="dataformat("
            print $3 $1 ",'\''YYYY-MM-DD HH'\:'NN'\:'SS'\.'sss)"
        } else if ($2=="date") {
            $3="dataformat("
            print $3 $1 ",'\''YYYY-MM-DD)"
        }
    }
' test.out
```

Also not sure what you want to do about the other lines that do not match... You can add an `else` to the end that does a simple `print` (defaults to printing the unmodified line), or maybe a `print` of specific fields.

Please note that the formatting is helpful in seeing how your blocks nest! This is perfectly valid syntax, the shell takes multi-line single-quoted strings just fine and awk will also be pretty happy with them. I recommend you use that more readable formatting of your awk scripts.

Comment: Ha, I did exactly what you did: adding newlines and indentation to the OP's code. Nice.